# How to write and read contents containing complex json data?

Tags: android, json, sharedpreferences

friends:

I  get a response from remote server as follows on Android:

```
{
"items": {
    "persons": [
        {
            "id": "200120",
            "name": "Bill"
        },
        {
            "id": "200121",
            "name": "Jim"
        }
    ],
    "tasks": [
        {
            "id": "001",
            "name": "Fetch ten books",
            "deadline": "5:30 p.m.",
            "scores": "10"
        },
        {
            "id": "002",
            "name": "Fetch thirty books",
            "deadline": "5:30 p.m.",
            "scores": "30"
        }
    ],
    "intro": "This is a funny game."
},
"otherObj": []
}
```

And I want to save it to phones. I do not think it a good choice to save it into databases. However it read not fast if put the response to `SharedPreferences` file. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to save this data into database as these value are dynamic and will change time to time.

In your Activity, call the API and get JSON as response and then parse this JSON and show it on device.

To store it on device u can use Singleton class also.

For JSON parser refer to http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm

Comment: Thanks to your answer @VipSha. As you say, if I want a person's name , "Bill" for example, how I can get it easily and fast like `singletonInstance.get(id)` and the `get` need not know the whole persons info?

Comment: Its all depends on how you are storing data into singleton. Create a getter setter class "Person" with two variable (Id, Name) and in singleton, create an array of "Person" and store data into that array.

Comment: How to store the array of "Person"? Files? Is there good method to traverse the files?

Comment: No. not in files. Store as "Persons[]" array. Each element of this array will store ID and NAME.
Call API at launch of app and then store all data in singleton and access data quickly and smoothly.

Comment: But we need persistionlized the data.

Comment: Persistency can be achieved by calling API and updating singleton after short periods. For that, a class should be created which calls the API and update the values in singleton. Call this class at launch of app and at the time of refreshing the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can first save your data into objects and at last into Object Array and then Save to database.(If your data is dynamic it is better you only deal with Object not database)

For saving to database you can use

```
db.beginTransaction();
for(object : ObjectArray){
   db.dboperation();
}
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();
```